# Can reject_if be used to reject a nested resource if all fields except one is blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I know that you can have:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :foo, :reject_if => proc { |a| a[:bar].blank? }
```

Is there a way to instead say something like

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :foo, :reject_if => blah[:bar].blank? and flah[:bar].blank?
```

or

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :foo, :reject_if => all fields except record_date.blank?
```

Thanks

Comment: Same question. Listing all blank fields in a proc is not very DRY... I have a nested form with a select box with default value (can't be blank). I want to ignore that value but I haven't seen something clean...

Answer (score 9):

I'm a bit late on this, but you can do :

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :foo, 
                               reject_if: ->(attributes){ 
                                 attributes.except(:key).values.all?( &:blank? ) 
                               }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer -- it's clean and effective.

Comment: thanks ! Another late note : beware of string keys when using `except`. You can use `attributes.with_indifferent_access` to work around these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this : https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2501-any_blank-and-all_blank-options-for-accepts_nested_attributes_for-reject_if

This worked fine for me:

```
reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes.all? {|k,v| v.blank? || ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].include?(k)} }
```

You can replace `['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].include?(k)` by `k == 'foo'` if there's only one exception but the first syntax makes the proc ready for multiple ones.