# Rails nested form: only save child if a name is provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My form lets you create a "child" on the same form as the parent, by entering that kid's name.

I only want to save the child record if a name was provided. In other words, I don't want to save a child with a blank name. I only want to create the child object if a name was provided.

What's a good way to do that?

Comment: You may find it useful to use reject_if. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088331/can-reject-if-be-used-to-reject-a-nested-resource-if-all-fields-except-one-is-bl) is the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for):

> **:reject_if**
>
> Allows you to specify a Proc or a Symbol pointing to a method that
>   checks whether a record should be built for a certain attribute hash.
>   The hash is passed to the supplied Proc or the method and it should
>   return either true or false. When no :reject_if is specified, a record
>   will be built for all attribute hashes that do not have a _destroy
>   value that evaluates to true. Passing :all_blank instead of a Proc
>   will create a proc that will reject a record where all the attributes
>   are blank excluding any value for _destroy.

So, we need to:

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

```
  has_many :kids

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :kids, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes[:name].blank? }

end
```